# direct upload with cloudinary - 'No such file or directory' error, probably is a mistake somewhere on my code of ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-uploading, cloudinary

I am trying to direct upload an image uploaded on a form to my cloudinary cloud.

This it edit form for a user on my code:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

<% if @user.name == nil %>
  <div>  
    <label for="user_username">Username or Email</label>
    <input id="user_username" name="user[username]" size="30" type="text"  />
  </div> 
<% else %>
    <div>
      <%= f.label :username_or_Email %>
      <%= f.text_field :username %> 
    </div>
<% end %> 

    <div>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %> 
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>

    <div>
      <%= file_field_tag 'image' %>
    </div>
  <div><%= f.submit "Update", :class => 'btn' %></div>  
<% end %>
```

My user controller to where this is submitted has the line called:

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(params[:image], :public_id => @user.username)
```

This line is provided in Cloudinary Documentation, the error I am getting is:

> No such file or directory - Screen Shot 2012-07-26 at 3.26.05 PM.png

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ueS/aqqCtsIH7ikVA1pq4LfWn044xltFnPQ6Dc0yQXE=",
 "user"=>{"username"=>"asuri@yahoo.com",
 "name"=>"Ankit Suri",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "image"=>"Screen Shot 2012-07-26 at 3.26.05 PM.png",
 "commit"=>"Update",
 "id"=>"P9q5l9gmea"}
```

Can someone please figure out where the error is?

Answer (score 2):

In order to upload files in your Rails form, you need to make sure it is using `Multipart`.

Simply change your `form_for` call as follows:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

In addition, you should also consider using [CarrierWave](http://cloudinary.com/blog/ruby_on_rails_image_uploads_with_carrierwave_and_cloudinary) or [Attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) for managing image uploads.

Answer (score 0):

What about your **cloudinary.yml** file?
you can download it using this link: http://cloudinary.com/console/cloudinary.yml and place it under your `config/` directory